# Can you please return the reputation scores in addition to the reputation changes?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, reputation

As by far and large (one of) the (two) largest consumer of `/users/*/reputation`<sup>1</sup> , I humbly request an addition to this route.

What I'd love to see is getting the reputation score in addition to the reputation changes, since this API route only gives me a partial view of the picture (I don't get updates fro downvotes cast; rep recalcs; suggested edits that get accepted; etc.). The main gripe with this is then that people see the reputation grow from 8,991 to 9,001 from an upvote, then reload the page and find out their reputation is *not* over nine thousand after all as they downvoted a post in the meantime in some other tab.

If I used tools that already do exist, I'd have to double the amount of calls to also hit `/users/{id}/` (and discard most of the returned information; I guess filters will help there in v2) and I already feel like SO Live! could do with making less calls.

I understand that getting the reputation score at an arbitrary second in time is quite expensive, so feel free to making this field optional and make it return the *current* reputation score at the time of calling, and not at `totime` seconds since Epoch.

<sup>**1:** [SO Live!](https://stackapps.com/questions/1703/so-live-live-updates-to-your-reputation-score) (I dunno if either or both editions) [generated last year 535k API calls](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/stack-exchange-api-usage-stats-and-api-2-0-plans/). The `/users/*/reputation` route got called 1.3m times. I only use that route, so I'm responsible for 41% of that route's usage — The math is simple. :)</sup>

Comment: Those stats aren't for a whole year, but for a month; just FYI.